# Lex word counter not running properly. Possible issue with opening file

Tags: c, file, lex

I'm working on a Lex program to pull a string of text from a file and count the number of words, characters and lines inside of the text file. I have the following code in place right now.

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int wordCount=0, charCount=0, lineCount=0;
%}

characters=[a-zA-z0-9]
word {characters}+
line \n

%%
{line} {charCount++; lineCount++;}
{word} {wordCount++; charCount+=strlen(yytext);}
. {charCount++;}
%%
int main(int arg, char *argv[]){
    
    extern FILE *yyin;
    yyin=fopen(argv[0],"r");
    yylex();
    printf("characters: %d\nwords: %d\nlines: %d\n",charCount,wordCount,lineCount);
    yyin=fclose(argv[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

The text file that I'm using is such

```
Hello world
Testing Testing 123
What!
I can't hear you
```

The code compiles and runs but it prints out this result when it runs.

```
characters: 28072
words: 2
lines: 23
```

This occurs even with an empty file.

I believe that I have the right idea but it seems like the file isn't being read properly and I'm not sure what is wrong. I was under the impression that this is how you open a file in Lex but I'm not sure if this is where I went wrong or if the issue is somewhere else. I apologize if the answer is blindingly obvious but I'm so rusty with C that flakes fall off as I type and Lex is uncharted territory for me.

Thank you for any help at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be opening `argv[1]`. `argv[0]` will open your executable file.

Also you should call `fclose(yyin)`. `fclose` expects a the file pointer, not the file name. I'm a bit surprised your program compiled.

Adding a little bit more error checking and some additional debugging information might have helped you to figure out what was wrong. What I mean is something like this:

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    extern FILE *yyin;
    if (argc != 2)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s <input_file>\n", argv[0]);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Opening file %s\n", argv[1]);
    yyin=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if (!yyin)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open %s\n", argv[1]);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    yylex();
    printf("characters: %d\nwords: %d\nlines: %d\n",charCount,wordCount,lineCount);
    fclose(yyin);
    return 0;
}
```

This checks that the an input file has been specified on the command line, printing a usage message if not.
It also prints the name of the file that it's trying to open and checks the file has been opened successfully.

Comment: Apologies for the brief delay in replying, I was beating my head against something hard for missing that. Rust or no rust, that's a really bad oversight on my part. It's still not counting the words correctly but I can fix that. Everything else is working perfectly now. Thank you so much for putting up with my incompetence!

Comment: No worries, happens to us all.